# Прокрутка строк в таблице на мобильной версии

Tags: javascript, php, css, flexbox, прокрутка

Есть такая таблица элементов:

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="el"></div>
<div class="el"></div>
<div class="el"></div>
...
</div>
```

Получается грид в 4 элемента на 2 строки.

Сейчас с адаптивом все элементы просто сдвигаются в зависимости от ширины экрана, до тех пор пока не останется по 1 в строчке. Но задача стоит следующая: в мобильной версии сделать просто скролл этих строк. Казалось бы решается только этим: 
`display: flex;
overflow: scroll;`
Но это дает мне одной строку скролла, а не две.
Я бы разделил этот грид на два, но это невозможно, каждый элемент .el генерится самой cms, поэтому я имею в распоряжении код с php типа:

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="el">
/*много php*/
</div>
</div>
```

Есть ли какое-то решение этой задачи? Может на php или js?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, теоретически 2 грида можно создавать с помощью js "на лету" и в цикле заполнять их элементами:

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.el');

const wrap1 = document.createElement('div');
const wrap2 = document.createElement('div');
wrap1.setAttribute('class', 'grid');
wrap2.setAttribute('class', 'grid');

for(let i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
  if(i<els.length/2) {
    wrap1.innerHTML += els[i].outerHTML;
    els[i].parentNode.replaceChild(wrap1, els[i]);
  }
  else {
    wrap2.innerHTML += els[i].outerHTML;
    els[i].parentNode.replaceChild(wrap2, els[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
}
.el {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">контент 1</div>
<div class="el">контент 2</div>
<div class="el">контент 3</div>
<div class="el">контент 4</div>
<div class="el">контент 5</div>
<div class="el">контент 6</div>
<div class="el">контент 7</div>
<div class="el">контент 8</div>
```

Comment: Почему-то не воспринимает этот код, ошибка где-то здесь if(i<els.length/2)

Comment: @StanDan, ну, здесь же всё работает - значит, какая-то проблема на Вашей стороне